# Create custom forms inside the setup project

Tags: c#-4.0, setup-project

Is it possible to create custom forms inside your setup project?
[image]

The reason for this is because I would like to add a form where it will allow the user to:
1. enter the username and password to be written in the configuration file
2. enter new configurations at post installation.

Answer (score 1):

There are only the canned dialogs you can add, right-click Start in that dialog and Add dialog. TextBoxes() would work, but there is no support for a password protection that I can see. In the textboxes dialog you end up with the values in properties called EDITA1, EDITA2 and you pass those to custom actions as [EDITA1] etc, they are case-sensitive, and the way they are passed depends on what kind of custom action you use to write into the text file.

If you have a post installation program that can change that configuration, it's often better to run that the first time your app runs. You can have a modern UI, it's much easier to test and debug, it runs with the user's credentials (custom actions don't) and you are creating that code anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any link that you can share to me that I can look into?

Comment: Link for which part, sorry?

Comment: I think this is more like creating a custom setup form. That would accommodate the requirement.